# How can place my desktop application to be placed in dock when close button is clicked in macOS?

Tags: javascript, macos

I want to place my desktop application in dock when close button is clicked. How can I do that?

Comment: Is this some sort of weird desktop application you've written in Javascript, or is that tag just not applicable here?

Answer (score 0):

While the application is open, right click on the icon in the dock, go to "Options", select "Keep in Dock." Now when you close the application the icon will stay in the dock.